# Getting Started: How can I create a server-side application to decipher a code and take an action?

Tags: python

So, I have minimal experience with Python, but I am very eager to learn. At my university, I am working in a group research lab where we are expanding on some previous research. Our next task is to create 2 applications:

The Client to Server application needs to be able to take inputs from a 4X4 keypad and send them to the server.

The Server to Client application needs to be able to take the codes sent and perform actions from them. For example:

1: Sends a message to the First-Aid team nearest to the location
2: Sends a message to the Hospital service
3: Sends a message to ...
D: No action is performed as this only acknowledges the end of the message

I definitely do not want my project done for me, of course. I'm just not sure how to get started. If anybody could provide resources or a good starting point, I would appreciate it dearly.

Thanks!

Comment: This is likely too broad. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this using TCP socket programming.

Try setting up two servers. One will be a client and other can be a server (Proxy server if you want it to connect to another server). On receiving inputs from the client the server which is listening reads the data and performs the task.

You can get started with socket programming here:

Visit

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

or

https://realpython.com/python-sockets/